# Tensorboard bounding box limit in eval of images

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, tensorboard

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GARM7.png) [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgZKS.png) When looking at eval results on tensorboard training an object detection model, not all bounding boxes around every object is made. Since there's a limit to how many bounding boxes are shown, however that can cause a lot of confusion about the results of my training. When I make my inference graph and test it I can change the code where there are no limits on the number of bounding boxes. So wanted to know where can I do the same for tensorboard.

`max_boxes_to_draw=None`

`vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
      max_boxes_to_draw=None,
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)`

This code is from the `object_detection_tutorial` Jupyter notebook that was provided with tensorflow. I had to add the line above to get this to work as shown in the pictures.

Answer (score 2):

In the config file, add the [field](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/58856e2b8b766e076d13afa935324d517fa9388f/research/object_detection/protos/eval.proto#L54) `max_num_boxes_to_visualize` and change it to a larger value. if not added the default value is 20.
For example

```
eval_config: {
  num_examples: xxxx
  max_num_boxes_to_visualize: 100
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to xx evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: xxx
}
```

this will set the value to 100.